# Make a directory from one container available to another one while keeping files from the original one

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

Let's say you have an image with a Rails application, containing assets. And you want to serve them from another container running Nginx.

From what I gather, mounting a volume makes the contents of a directory disappear. So, if you mount one volume into two containers, like,

```
volumes:
  assets:
services:
  app:
    volumes:
      assets:/app/public/assets
  nginx:
    volumes:
      assets:/assets
```

they both will see an empty folder. You can very well fill it up by hand. But if you were to deploy a newer version of the Rails app image, those two won't see the changes.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to handle files without proxying them to Rails app or copying them from container to container?

**UPD** First container with non-empty directory that gets the volume mounted determines its initial content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following lines before starting Rails to your Rails image's `Dockerfile` (`CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`):

```
rm -r /assets/*
cp -r /app/public/assets/* /assets
```

And mount the volume into `/assets` for both services.

This way every time your container restarts (on `docker stack deploy` when it's changed), the volume is refilled with fresh assets that is visible to nginx container.

Comment: So I do that in Rails container? And by "at the end" you mean before starting Rails? And `rails_asset` is what exacty? Copy of `/app/public/assets`? So by deleting a folder where a volume is mounted and filling it up docker will notice the changes? And for that I have to keep assets in two places in the image? Or on second thought, I can move them to `/app/public/new-assets` after build, and copy to `/app/public/assets` on launch?

Comment: yes. rails_asset is your rail assets path. either copy or move can do, the point is to do it at launch.

Comment: Well, you can't remove the folder itself, you've got to: `rm -rf /assets/* && cp -r /app/public/assets/* /assets`. Then, I tried it locally, and `docker stack deploy` doesn't restart the container (and container id doesn't change), even so the image has changed. I believe it restarts when `docker-compose.yml` changes. Although, that seems strange. So, doing this on container start doesn't seem reliable. It's probably best to copy files with `docker exec` after `docker stack deploy`. Am I missing something? Well, it may be because of that "image could not be accessed on a registry..." issue...

Comment: It probably has to do with [`image ... could not be accessed on a registry to record its digest`](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34153) issue. It seems to work on production. Thanks for the idea :)